# Detener una cosulta en tiempo real en firebase firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Tengo este problema: estoy haciendo una consulta en tiempo real a firestore de firebase en javascript
mi codigo es el siguiente:

```
  first = db.collection("messages")
    .where("codeConversation", "==", codeConversation)
    .orderBy("date", "desc")
    .limit(25);

  first.onSnapshot(function (querySnapshot) {

//.. demás ejecución
```

Leí [la documentación](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen?authuser=0#detach_a_listener) de cómo detenerlo pero no entiendo cómo aplicarlo dice que debe ser lo siguiente:

```
var unsubscribe = db.collection("cities")
    .onSnapshot(function () {});
// ... 
// Stop listening to changes
unsubscribe();
```

intenté reemplazar el código anterior por mi propia consulta de la siguiente forma para detenerlo pero no funcionó

```
 var unsubscribe =  db.collection("messages")
        .where("codeConversation", "==", codeConversation)
        .orderBy("date", "desc")
        .limit(25).onSnapshot(function (querySnapshot) {
    // ... demás ejecución

    // Stop listening to changes
    unsubscribe();
```

Comment: La doc dice también que debes implementar un manejo de errores por si el código falla: *En ocasiones, una escucha puede fallar (por ejemplo, debido a los permisos de seguridad o si intentas escuchar una consulta no válida). (Obtén más información sobre las consultas válidas y no válidas). Para solucionar estas fallas, puedes proporcionar una devolución de llamada de error cuando adjuntes el agente de escucha de instantáneas. Después de un error, el agente de escucha no recibirá más eventos y no será necesario desvincularlo.* En el mismo enlace de tu pregunta muestran cómo hacerlo.

Comment: pero la cunsulta no tiene error, lo que no puedo hacer es desvincularla, la consulta funciona bien

Comment: El error puede ser por otro motivo, como permisos u otros. Siempre conviene capturar errores, no dar por hecho que siempre funcionará porque sí.

Comment: Pero, no hay permisos para detener una escucha pero sí para comenzarlas? Ya puse el `catch` pero no me arroja errores